# Email notifications when a VSTS release is successful

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am getting email notifications whenever a release in VSTS is successful, but the content of the email is limited.

Is there any way in VSTS to detail the stories that contributed to a release? i.e. list the stories linked to the commits that went into the release.

I am using VSTS with git.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to change the email content/format for VSTS email notifications.

You can view details by clicking the release link in the email content.

[image]

Else, you set notifications by [Send Email](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rvo.SendEmailTask) task. You can add the task at the end of the last release environment. After all the previous environments and tasks are succeed, the task Send Email will execute, and you can specify the content, subject etc as you need.